# PHP - Search string then delete until end of that string

Tags: php, string

I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et ipsum ac tellus hendrerit semper in sit amet nulla.';
```

If found the string `hendrerit semper`, delete from that string until the end of that string.

The result should be:

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et ipsum ac tellus';
```

Can you guys guide me how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is absolutely basic string manipulation - http://www.whathaveyoutried.com - strpos() and substr() might give you a clue

Comment: @MarkBaker - definitely, but sometimes its hard to know what to search to get the correct answer. Hopefully thats the case here and hes not just lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`substring` to get a substring and `strpos` to find the position

```
echo substr( $string, 0, strpos( $string, 'hendrerit semper' ) );
```

Comment: thank you so much, i have been struggling with google and str_replace for hours!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Note that you should always check the return value of `strpos` before using it further.

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et ipsum ac tellus hendrerit semper in sit amet nulla.';
$search = 'hendrerit semper';
if (strpos($string, $search) === false) {
    // $search not found in $string
    $result = false;
}
else {
    $result = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, $search));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [PHP: strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Note that you have a 'before needle' parameter.

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et ipsum ac tellus hendrerit semper in sit amet nulla.';
echo strstr($string, 'hendrerit semper', true) . "\n";exit;
```

Will give you: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In et ipsum ac tellus"